# Checking a char array for invalid characters

Tags: arrays, c, string, char

I'm attempting to create a function that when passed an array, checks it against an array of valid characters and returns true if they are all valid, or false if just one of them is not.

However my second assert is failing despite there being an invalid character present.

```
void test (void)
{   
   char testArr1[MAXGRIDHW][MAXGRIDHW] = {{"..."},
                                          {"..."},
                                          {"..."}};

   char testArr2[MAXGRIDHW][MAXGRIDHW] = {{"..z"},
                                          {"..."},
                                          {"..."}};

   assert(noInvalidLetters(testArr1) == true);
   assert(noInvalidLetters(testArr2) == false);

}

bool noInvalidLetters (char b[][MAXGRIDHW])
{
   int i, j;
   bool valid;
   const char validChars[MAXVALIDCHARS] = {'k', 'K', 'r', 'R', 'g', 'G', 'y',
                                           'Y', 'b', 'B', 'm', 'M', 'c', 'C',
                                           'w', 'W', '.'};

   for (i = 0; i < MAXGRIDHW; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < MAXGRIDHW; j++) {
         if (strchr(validChars, b[i][j])){
            valid = true;
         } else {
            valid = false;
         }
      }
   }
   return valid;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find a valid character, `valid` should not be set back to true. Then, an invalid character followed by a valid character would be "valid". In fact, you don't need to have a boolean at all. You can just return early:

```c
bool noInvalidLetters (char b[][MAXGRIDHW])
{
   int i, j;
   const char validChars[MAXVALIDCHARS] = {'k', 'K', 'r', 'R', 'g', 'G', 'y',
                                           'Y', 'b', 'B', 'm', 'M', 'c', 'C',
                                           'w', 'W', '.'};

   for (i = 0; i < MAXGRIDHW; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < MAXGRIDHW; j++) {
         if (!strchr(validChars, b[i][j])){
            // invalid char so just say it's invalid
            return false;
         }
      }
   }
   // found no invalid chars so must be all valid
   return true;
}
```